# Is there any advantages of passing array as int A[] rather than int *A?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

Say I declare a function passing array as a pointer:

`void fun(int *A, int n);`

If I use an array specific pointer instead, i.e.

`void fun(int A[], int n);`

Is there any particular advantage to it?

Comment: `int A[]` is exactly equivalent to `int *A` (when used as function parameter).

Comment: You could perhaps make the argument that it shows more intent that the parameter is an array versus a pointer to a single item but that's stretching it, especially since you're likely passing a size along with it and you always name everything well enough to understand what it is.

Comment: The difference is purely stylistic. I personally prefer `int A[]` because it makes it clearer that the pointer is meant to point to an array, and not a single `int`. To the compiler, the two are exactly equivalent.

Comment: Please do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the languages.

Comment: The only advantage is to the code maintainer indicating that an array is being passed in rather than a pointer to a single object.  However, since passing in an array by pointer *as a parameter* is so common, the use of the idiom is probably futile, since passing an array by pointer can only be confirmed by code inspection or trusting the comments.

Comment: @EricPostpischil what if you don't know if there's a difference?

Comment: @MarkRansom: The rule is not based on whether or not there **is** a difference. The rules is based on whether you are **asking about** a difference or interaction. If the question is “How do C and C++ differ” in some regard, then you might tag both languages. If you are not asking about a difference or interaction, then do not use both tags.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should be using `std::vector` instead of arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This answer speaks to C.)

For an `int` array with size `[]`, there are no differences to the compiler, because C 2018 6.7.6.3 7 says:

> A declaration of a parameter as "array of *type*" shall be adjusted to "qualified pointer to *type*", where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation…

However, for some type `T` in general, there is a difference. Per C 2018 6.7.6.2 1, in a declaration of an array, the element type must be complete, even if the array will be adjusted to a pointer later:

> … The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type…

Consider `typedef int T[];`, which defines `T` to be an alias for `int []`, which is an array of `int` with an unknown number of elements. This type is incomplete because the number of elements is unknown. So we cannot declare an array of `T`. In contrast, a pointer may point to an incomplete type. So `void fun(T *A, int n);` is allowed, but `void fun(T A[], int n);` is not allowed because it violates 6.7.6.2 1.

Another difference is if the size is specified and is variable. Then it may be evaluated when the function is called. (The C standard is not explicit about this, but Clang and GCC evaluate it.) For example, given a function definition `void fun(int A[printf("Hello, world.\n")], int n) { … }`, when `fun` is called, “Hello, world.” will be printed. This of course does not happen with `void fun(int *A, int n) { … }`.

Comment: meh, thats the problem with tagging both. Honestly, I do not care much about C, but now I do have to ask you: Is this the same in C++ or is it different?